# при нажатии на любую первую ячейку выполняется одна ф-ция, в остальных случаях

Tags: jquery

Имеется таблица, при нажатии на любую первую ячейку выполняется метод `initExpandableTableRows()`, а если нажать на любую другую ячейку, то выполняется метод `initTableRows()`. Код неверный. Я новичок

```
function addOnclickToDatatableRows() {
    var tds = $('[id*=dataTable] tr td:first-child').get();
    var trs = $('[id*=dataTable] tbody:first tr').get();
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        tds[i].onclick = new Function("selectFirstCell()");
        trs[i].onclick = new Function("selectRow()");
    }


}

function selectFirstCell() {
    initExpandableTableRows();
}

function selectRow(){
    initTableRows();

}
```

Comment: а откуда вообще этот код взялся?

Answer (score 0):

Ваш пример похож на псевдокод, но из него, если я правильно все понял, ответ может быть таким:

```js
$rows = $('table tr');
$cols_first = $rows.find('td:first-of-type');
$cols_secnd = $rows.find('td:not(:first-of-type)');

$cols_first.click(function() {
  alert('cols_first');
});

$cols_secnd.click(function() {
  alert('cols_secnd');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Уточните вопрос, если код делает не то, что вы спросили.

Comment: почему псевдокод? вполне рабочий

Comment: Тогда ждем автора, мне до конца вопрос не ясен...

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще с проверкой на индекс - `.index()` :

```js
var 
    table = $('table'),
    trs = table.find('tr'),
    tds = trs.find('td');


tds.click(function(){
  if($(this).index() === 0){
    selectFirstCell();
    
  }else if($(this).index() !== 0){
    selectRow();
  }     
});


function selectFirstCell() {
//     initExpandableTableRows();
  alert('initExpandableTableRows');
}

function selectRow(){
//     initTableRows();
  alert('initTableRows');

}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  
<table> 
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```